# How to prevent Tcl from printing the value being set?

Tags: tcl

A call to a Tcl procedure that sets a variable seems to print the value being set.

```
% proc a { } { set b "I don't want that!" }
% a
I don't want that!
```

How to prevent that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a bare `return`:

```
% proc a { } { set b "I don't want that!" ; return }
```

Note that the value isn't actually printed by the code in question. The `set` command returns the value, and the `a` command returns the value of its last executed command. If you run the `a` command in an interactive tclsh* session, the return value is printed before the next prompt, but if you execute `a` non-interactively in a script, it won't be printed.

---

*) or similar, like tkcon.

Comment: Another "trick" for interactive sessions is to append `; list` a `set` command: the bare `list` returns an empty string making the interactive shell print nothing for the value it returns — while "shadowing" the result of the execution of the `set` command.